# Symfony-2 > login & logout routes with placeholders

Tags: security, symfony, routes, placeholder

I am using Symfony-2 to implement my application.
I need my login and logout routes to have some placeholders, but I don't manage to define it well in *routing.yml* and *security.yml* files. 
I want to have something like:
`www.mysite.com/{client_slug}/panel`

and under it other secured pages:
`www.mysite.com/{client_slug}/panel/.*`
When someone tries to navigate to one of these pages, he/she should be redirected to:
`www.mysite.com/{client_slug}/login`
and after clicking *logout*, user should be redirected to something like:
`www.mysite.com/{client_slug}/goodbye`

I tried several things ([http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=37809)](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=37809) but at the moment the only thing I achieved was that in my login url the text **{client_slug}** appears:

`www.mysite.com/my-cliend-slug/panel`
      redirects to
`www.mysite.com/{client_slug}/login`

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: _security_login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /goodbye
        security: true
        anonymous: true
```

**routing.yml**

```
_security_login:
    pattern:  /{_client_slug}/login
    defaults: { _controller: MyAppBackendBundle:Security:login }

_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check

_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout

_admin_panel:
    pattern:  /{_client_slug}/panel
    defaults: { _controller: MyAppBackendBundle:AdminPanel:index }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the *relevant* bits of your routing.yml and security.yml files, so we can make sure your access control and firewals are set up correctly.

Comment: Just added relevant parts to the original question.

Comment: What should ```_client_slug``` contain?

Comment: It is a string with the slug of the client name. The application has panels for each client, and the url should contain its slug. For example, if the client is called "Manolo and sons", the slug will be simply manolo-and-sons. It is going to serve during the whole session in order to validate access for different modules.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. I've read everything from here (http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=37809) and for me it works with a few extra lines.

Here is my security.yml

```
       login_area:
            pattern:    ^/[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+/login$
            anonymous:  ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+/.*
            form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
```

The login and login_path definitions:

```
login:
    pattern:  /{_client}/login
    defaults: { _controller: GNCApplicationBaseBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:  /{_client}/login_check
```

And I made an EventListener, which will be called at the kernel.request event:

```
acme.system.client.listener:
        class: Acme\System\ClientBundle\EventListener\ClientListener
        arguments: [@router, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 10 }
```

The important attribute is the priority. In the Symfony Documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-event-listener) it shows that the RouterListener starts with a priority 32 and the Firewall at 8. So I choose to call my custom EventListener right before the Firewall and set the _client-attribute manually in the router-context:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {

        $clientIdentifier = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_client');
        $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_client', $clientIdentifier);

    }
```

And it works well for me.

I'm currently using Symfony 2.2.0-RC3.

Comment: Manixx; you don't have bad English *at all*! You write better than many native speakers. I'm removing your apology because it truly is totally unnecessary.