# Symfony security placeholders

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm trying to find out if there is a possibility to use placeholders in the security.yml config of Symfony.

**I have the following security.yml:**

`order_area:
      pattern:    ^/{_checkout}/
      anonymous:  ~
      provider:   ehv_customer
      security:   true
      context:    customer`

I'm building a checkout process for multiple languages, but I don't want to use one standard language to handle the routing e.g. /checkout/1, /checkout/2. The checkout is protected by the Symfony firewall to only allow customers logged in.

Is there a way I can define a placeholder to handle the security firewall routing per language. The following link is an other example of the problem but it didn't work for me: [Symfony-2 > login & logout routes with placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078055/symfony-2-login-logout-routes-with-placeholders). I could also use a prefix but that's my last option.

Perhaps it's possible to add firewall rules through PHP instead of YML or XML?

Symfony version: **2.5.3**

Comment: I possibly found a solution to this problem by putting the whole website under the firewall and thus limiting specific urls for security. But I currently do not know if it will produce new problems because I have other firewall rules which may conflict with this: `pattern: ^/.*` and `pattern: ^/admin/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my comment I finally achieved to solve this issue by creating a firewall rule that handles the whole website:

`customer_area:
      pattern:    ^/.*
      anonymous:  ~
      provider:   ehv_customer
      security:   true
      context:    customer`

Other firewall rules that could conflict with this rule should be stated first. For handling of the login/logout form and restricting certain parts of the website, I used a controller and the security.context service.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on the [Symfony Localization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) component, which uses the `_locale` parameter. It may be usable in security.yml patterns, but you'll have to test to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately it only works in the routing not in security.yml

Comment: It looks like pattern matching is all you can do then. Maybe you can construct a regular expression that fits your needs.

Comment: Well that ain't gonna work for me too because the URL starts with a dynamic string. I can only apply a regular expression if my url starts with a prefix. Thanks anyways.